# how to embed PDF file into iframe using php

Tags: javascript, php, html, iframe, fopen

I have simple PDF file in my directory and I use `fopen` to open PDF file. When I try to embed it on into html `iframe`, the file is not showing up. I know I can specify the source as `iframe` attribute but I want to do it using PHP.

```
<?php
$myfile = fopen("http://ipaddress/file.pdf", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
fclose($myfile);
?>

<body>
<iframe src="<?php $myfile; ?>#toolbar=0&navpanes=0&scrollbar=0" width="1000" height="1000"></iframe>
</body>
```

Comment: You are mixing 2 very different things here. fopen of php returns the contents of the file but iframe src expects a url.

Comment: Why are you needing PHP if you already have access to the URL of the PDF, why not just use the URL directly?

Comment: @NawedKhan what is the alternative? I originally wanted to put path from local drive like c or network drive but I do not thing it will work so I'm experimenting with different methods.

Comment: @PeterFeatherstone I wanted to use the file from a network drive but after trying different methods of using `file:` with 3 and 5 back and front slashes and different combinations it just does not seem to work in chromium, therefore I decided to try it with use of PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick.

```
<body>
<iframe src="http://ipaddress/file.pdf" width="1000" height="1000"></iframe>
</body>
```

If the file is local you can put local file URL. But the file will not be accessible on internet.
For example:

```
 file:///D:/WebDesign/HTML/test/file.pdf
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I already discovered this but is there any way to access the file on the internet from local drive? I know it is a massive security risk and browsers do not allow you to do this, but is it possible to do it using PHP or Javascript? How about shared network drive? what would I need to specify? is it the IP name of the server? do I need to change some settings in Bitnami wampstack? any suggestions?

Comment: you will need a static, public facing IP address for your local computer or network drive. Best solution is to upload the files on internet that has a url.

Comment: Thank You Sir. I will try to find the IP address from our network administrator.